# Can I install coldfusion 9 and coldfusion 8 on the same server?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8

Can I install ***coldfusion 8*** and ***coldfusion 9*** on the same server and use them separately?

Great thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how you do the install: [Installing Multiple Versions of ColdFusion Together](http://www.cfgothchic.com/blog/post.cfm/presentation-installing-multiple-versions-of-coldfusion-together) - Presentation at Philadelphia CFUG meeting by Daria Norris

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely. Basically there is no difference from using few instances of same version, like described in the [Installing the J2EE Configuration](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/installj2ee_01.html) help section.

P.S. Vote for ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can..
the main issue here is how your webserver works out which one to use when.
the best way to do this is to have two different webservers (apache and IIS) serving the two different versions of CF.

Other ways would be..

- to have WSConfig point to the same proxy port for both versions of CF but then you could only run one at a time.
- to have WSConfig bind two different sets of file extensions (ie .cfm8 goes to CF8 and .cfm goes to CF9

None of these are really great solutions but it depends on what you are trying to achieve.